# JQuery Blur Validation Problem

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, blur

I have a simple form that I want to validate using blur if the text field is empty.

The below code should work, but keeps alerting me even if I pop in some text, please, what am I doing wrong?

```
var name = $("input#name").val();
$("input#name").blur(function() 
{
      if (('input#name:empty'))
      {
            // Testing
            alert('Empty');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`$(this).val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
$("input#name").blur(function() {
   if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
     // Testing
     alert('Empty');
   }
});
```

Currently you're checking `if('input#name:empty')` which is true, any string is going to be `true` in JavaScript (which is weakly typed).  Also the [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) checks that it has no *child elements*, not that its *value* is empty, so check that the value is an empty string, or the `.length` is empty like I have above :)

Also, unless there is the possibility of this ID being on another element type you don't want to match, `#name` will suffice and be faster, the `input` prefix is superfluous.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Nick. if you have some time, could you explain this bit please: if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
Thanks again!

Comment: @Keith - Certainly, `this` refers to that input DOM element inside any event handler like the function we're passing into [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/), wrapping it in [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) gets the jQuery wrapped version of it, which lets you use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get its value.  We're then checking if that string's length is greater than 0, meaning it has some characters in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input#name").blur(function() 
{
  var name = $(this).val();
  if (name.length == 0)
  {
        // Testing
        alert('Empty');
  }
});
```

Edit: Nick pointed out that the input text needs to checked when the blur happens.  If I make any more change, it will be just like his answer, so I stop here.

Comment: This approach doesn't work...you're getting the value when the page loaded, not what it was when the element's `blur` event fired, you need to get the value at that time.