# How do I keep track of when what is the text entered in the form when the user navigates away from the page?

Tags: forms, text

I have a piece of code like this.

```
<form method="get" action="{$self}" name="addcommentform">
<textarea title="{$enterComment}" name="comment" class="commentarea" </textarea>
<input class="Button" type="submit" value="{$postComment}" />
</form>
```

How do I keep track of when what is the text entered in the form's textarea when the user navigates away from the page?  I want to prompt the user with a warning message so he/she doesn't lose the text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript/jquery blur event, and if the user hasn't clicked the desired button have it display the form values. This might help [JQuery Blur Validation Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971244/jquery-blur-validation-problem)

Stu

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Javascript code snippet:

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/disableclose.html

This takes advantage of the window's `onbeforeunload` event which fires when the user is about to leave the page.